# JRI from Hive UDF / UDAF

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, rjava

I have R installed on some data nodes and can write Map reduce jobs to invoke R through JRI.

Next, to get R to be invoked through a hive query, I override the terminate method in GenericUDAFEvaluator and create Rengine objects there.

The old mapred job required me to do `-Dmapred.child.env="R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R"` before it could work.

When I do this in hive (via set mapred.child.env="R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R"; ) and then run a query, the job fails at setup.

More generally this succeeds from hive:

```
 select count(*) from some_table limit 10;
```

but this fails:

```
 set mapred.child.env='abc=pqr';
 select count(*) from some_table limit 10;
```

I have `hive-hwi-0.9.0-cdh4.1.1.jar` and `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.1.1`

Answer (score 1):

I removed the quotes from the set statement and it worked. So do:

`set mapred.child.env=abc=pqr;`

`select count(*) from some_table limit 10;`

This works